# Fixed row of a table made only by divs

Tags: html, css

I must make a table only by divs and I need to make the first row fixed on top when scrolling if I have overflow-y of the table posting my HTML and CSS here. I MUST NOT USE BOOTSTRAP!!!

I tried with position fixed ... but it "destroys" the css of the row and I don't have any other ideas.

```css
.table {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.calls-table {
  display: table;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  /* table-layout: fixed;*/
  width: 100%;
  color: #262626;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
}

.calls-table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.calls-table-row:hover {
  background-color: #80ffaa;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-row:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: auto;
}

.calls-table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.th {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.td {
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: #76605a;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
}

.first-td-row {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 17px 57px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 17px 57px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 1px 17px 57px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="calls-table">
    <div class="calls-table-row header-row first-td-row">
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">Time</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">Client name</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">Client email</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">IP</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">Location</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">Language</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">Waiting from</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">Taken by</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">Status</div>
    </div>
    <div class="calls-table-row">
      <div class="calls-table-cell td ">10:46</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">John Andrews</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">dj@aol.com</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">79.62.113.50</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Poland</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">English</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">0:47</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">-</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">waiting</div>
    </div>
    <div class="calls-table-row">
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">10:45</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Milena Ivanova</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">29_08@mypos.eu</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">82.119.81.30</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Bulgaria</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Bulgarian</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">1:23</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">-</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">waiting</div>
    </div>
    <div class="calls-table-row">
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">10:44</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Ivan Ivanov</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">i.f.ivanov@gmail.com</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">2.43.229.251</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">UK</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">English</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">0:29</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Petur Ivanov</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">On the line</div>
    </div>
    <div class="calls-table-row">
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">10:44</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">John Andrews</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">dj@aol.com</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">79.62.113.50</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Poland</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">English</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">0:47</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">-</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">waiting</div>
    </div>
    <div class="calls-table-row">
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">10:41</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Ivelina Smith</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">i.smith@gmail.com</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">21.11.69.249</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Netherlands</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Dutch</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">1:01</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Maria Atanasova</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Completed</div>
    </div>
    <div class="calls-table-row">
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">10:41</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Ivelina Smith</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">i.smith@gmail.com</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">21.11.69.249</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Netherlands</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Dutch</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">0:01</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Maria Atanasova</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Time out</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--calls-table-->
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fixed` css like this:

```css
.table {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.calls-table {
  display: table;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  /* table-layout: fixed;*/
  width: 100%;
  color: #262626;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.calls-table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.calls-table-row:hover {
  background-color: #80ffaa;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-row:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: auto;
}

.calls-table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.th {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.td {
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: #76605a;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
}
.calls-table-row.header-row.first-td-row {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    top: 0;
}
.first-td-row {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 17px 57px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 17px 57px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: 1px 17px 57px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="calls-table">
    <div class="calls-table-row header-row first-td-row">
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">Time</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">Client name</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">Client email</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">IP</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">Location</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">Language</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">Waiting from</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">Taken by</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell th">Status</div>
    </div>
    <div class="calls-table-row">
      <div class="calls-table-cell td ">10:46</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">John Andrews</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">dj@aol.com</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">79.62.113.50</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Poland</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">English</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">0:47</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">-</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">waiting</div>
    </div>
    <div class="calls-table-row">
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">10:45</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Milena Ivanova</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">29_08@mypos.eu</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">82.119.81.30</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Bulgaria</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Bulgarian</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">1:23</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">-</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">waiting</div>
    </div>
    <div class="calls-table-row">
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">10:44</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Ivan Ivanov</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">i.f.ivanov@gmail.com</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">2.43.229.251</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">UK</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">English</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">0:29</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Petur Ivanov</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">On the line</div>
    </div>
    <div class="calls-table-row">
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">10:44</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">John Andrews</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">dj@aol.com</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">79.62.113.50</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Poland</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">English</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">0:47</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">-</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">waiting</div>
    </div>
    <div class="calls-table-row">
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">10:41</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Ivelina Smith</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">i.smith@gmail.com</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">21.11.69.249</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Netherlands</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Dutch</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">1:01</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Maria Atanasova</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Completed</div>
    </div>
    <div class="calls-table-row">
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">10:41</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Ivelina Smith</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">i.smith@gmail.com</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">21.11.69.249</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Netherlands</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Dutch</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">0:01</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Maria Atanasova</div>
      <div class="calls-table-cell td">Time out</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--calls-table-->
</div>
```

Also check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tg8410u/)